# HTML table cell <td> grouping at row level

Tags: html, html-table

Is there any way to virtually group few `<td>` in a row in order to set style for those cells at once in one element instead of setting it multiple times for all cells separately?

This is purely server-side generated code, where I can apply specific css class to format text color of couple cells in a row, based on some logic.

This is not working:

```
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <div class="sometextcolor">
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
    </div>
  </tr>
```

no surprise as HTML 5 specs defines `<tr>` as

> Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements

Tried `colgroup` but that would affect all rows with same style.

Comment: You should take a look at css classes - that will give you a method to style common elements.  You can't wrap <td> elements inside a <div>

Comment: Yes that will help, but I need to dynamically change color of half of the row, based on the row content. So that would require changing css class for all those cells. Same job here - a change needed for all affected cells.

Comment: How are you intending to "dynamically" change the colours?  Via javascript?  You could still potentially get elements by their class name and set colour as required.  Maybe you need to explain a little more about the conditions for setting colours

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Comment: If you are generating the output server-side, then you can apply the appropriate class to the applicable <td>s.  As I noted in a previous comment, you can't wrap a group of <td> elements in a <div>.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and confirming that. Would you add this as an answer so I can accept it for other users?

Comment: Not entirely sure my comments justify the "answer" to your problem - more just a suggestion that your attempted approach to wrap the <td>s in a <div> is not valid HTML.  You can see from the couple of answers that have already been added that there are potentially a number of different ways to achieve what you need to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you try without table elements. write this type table with div cell are help full to using with complex JavaScript.
you can display dives as a table using CSS.
this is completely change idea so sorry but you may try without table element.
use CSS display property with these values table-row, table-cell, table-row-group, and more

Answer (score 0):

use below css to add style on specific cell in a row but it will add style to all of your table you can use class or id in table to specifically style your table

```
.Custom-Table tr td:nth-child(2), .Custom-Table tr td:nth-child(3){
      color: red !important;
 }
```

General

```
table tr td:nth-child(2), table tr td:nth-child(3){
     color: red !important;
}
```